# Invalid token error when calling Microsoft graph from Web API

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, sharepoint-online

What I need to do is to calling Microsoft graph from C# Web API. This is basically what my method looks like:

```
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = context.AcquireToken(clientId, clientCredential);
if (authenticationResult == null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the token");
}
return authenticationResult;
```

---

what i receive by this call is:

[image]

---

then my idea is to call microsoft graph passing this token (and i'm not even 100% sure that this is the correct way of implementing the implicit flow)...but after that i receive the "invalid token" error.

could anyone tell me where i'm doing wrong here?
Thank you alot!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the way you acquire the token.

This should be:

```
context.AcquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com", clientCredential);
```

The first parameter is the resource URI for the API you want a token for.

Also this is not implicit flow, it is client credentials flow where the app accesses an API as itself, using application permissions.

Comment: it works! i'm sorry but i'm completely new to this world :)
only one question... in order to access from my webapi to the groups of my AAD this is the correct flow, right?

Comment: As always, it depends. This flow is used usually when you don't have a signed in user who has access to the data. If your user does have access, it is better to use delegated permissions and one of the flows there. Application permissions effectively give your API organization-wide rights so I try to avoid using them unless necessary.